# Add link in ribbon - SP2013

Tags: 2013, ribbon, promoted-links, suite-links

I would like customizing my ribbon, but not in this way that is exemplified here [Custom actions in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/custom-actions-in-sharepoint-2013.html).

[image]
I need to add a link in the green stripe or gray (preferably in gray stripe).

In SP 2010 I changed the ribbon inside the masterpage, however, the SP2013 can't find where I can make this change.

I need to add a link that directs to the administrative (customized it) from my site.

Can anyone help me where I can make this change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since those are new to SharePoint 2013, you should know the terminologies and it will be easy to find..

The Green one is called **"Suite Bar"**, while the grey one (with Share, Follow buttons) are called **"Promoted Actions"**..

Using delegate you can have your custom Suite Bar or Promoted Actions.. Following tutorials should help:

[Add,Remove Links in Top Suitebar (SkyDrive,Sites,NewsFeed) in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[Add Links to Promoted Actions (Share,Follow,SYNC) in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/19/add-links-to-promoted-actions-sharefollowsync-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 11's new Developer Tools (F12) DOM Explorer really provides a great tool for figuring out exactly where to change certain things. If you right click on the ribbon and select 'Inspect Element' you'll be able to hover over different areas in the HTML and/or CSS to identify where you would need to make changes. There are multiple elements on this ribbon area that you may want to add links, but for example the left hand ribbon has links in an HTML Unordered List  the 'Browse' ribbon link was very easy to locate. Here is just a piece of it:

```
<span class="ms-cui-tt-span" unselectable="on">Browse</span>
```

You can even enter changes to see a live preview in your browser. This should help you to quickly identify and make then changes you desire. I use it all the time to help me edit 3rd party CSS themes.