# How to create a new custom link in the SharePoint Suite Bar (?) on the right

Tags: 2013

I need to create a `custom link` which open a custom application page. Here is a screenshot of what I exactly mean:

[image]

How can I create such a link on this bar which only opens a `.aspx` page?

**Update**
I need to do this

1. Without modifying the `masterpage`
2. packagable through module etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found on [Tobias Zimmergren's Blog](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages) you need to do the following:

Create an Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <!-- DelegateControl reference to the PromotedActions Delegate Control -->
  <Control ControlSrc="/_controltemplates/15/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/PromotedAction.ascx"
           Id="PromotedActions"
           Sequence="1" />

</Elements>
```

Create an User Control PromotedActions.aspx

```
<!-- Note: I've removed the actual Facebook-logic from this snippet for easier overview of the structure. -->
<a title="Share on Facebook" class="ms-promotedActionButton" style="display: inline-block;" href="#">
    <span class="s4-clust ms-promotedActionButton-icon" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
        <img style="top: 0px; position: absolute;" alt="Share" src="/_layouts/15/images/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/facebookshare.png"/>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-promotedActionButton-text">Post on Facebook</span>
</a>
```

Thats it!

Answer (score 2):

Modify your master page and add the link with desired name and url. It will fulfill your purpose.

Please have a look at this [article](http://academy.bindtuning.com/customize-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365-suite-bar/) for a start.

If you don't want to modify existing master page, you can do it through code by changing the `SuiteLinksDelegate Delegate Control`, please have a look [here](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages) for more information.

```
public partial class SuiteLinksDelegate : MySuiteLinksUserControl {
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Style);
        writer.Write(".ms-core-suiteLinkList {display: inline-block;}");
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "ms-core-suiteLinkList");
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul);

        // The true/false parameter means if it should be the active link or not - since I'm shooting off this to an external URL, it will never be active..
        RenderSuiteLink(writer, "http://timelog.tozit.com", "Time Report", "ReportYourTimeAwesomeness", false);

        writer.RenderEndTag();
        base.Render(writer);
    } }
```

Comment: I need to do it through a solution without modifying the masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't to update `master page`, you can achieve it using `JavaScript`. You need to know rendered html of the `SuiteBar links`, which is something like below.

[image]

So to add one more link below code can be helpful.

```
var customLi = "<li class='ms-core-suiteLink'><a class='ms-core-suiteLink-a' target='_blank' href='www.yourlink.com'>Your Custom Link</a></li>";
if(jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").length > 0){
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").children("ul").append(customLi);

}
else {
        jQuery("div#suiteLinksBox").html('<ul class="ms-core-suiteLinkList">' + customLi + '</ul>')
}
```

The result of above code will be

[image]

Refer this in detail at [Customize SharePoint 2013 suite bar](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/customize-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/)

Comment: I think it will be nearly the same for the Links in the bar below.

Comment: But one more: Isnt it possible to have such a link through a module, or anyting else which i could create for example like a custom action and put it in my feature?

Comment: How do you plan to deploy? `JavaScript` files can be placed in modules, which when deployed dumps files into Style Library.

Comment: I have a large solution (Visual Studio SP Solution with WSP output). This needs to deployed by the infrastructure team and a feature should be activated on a dedicated sitecollection to active this link for this sitecollection.

Comment: Does your solution contains modules of something like `Scripts`, there you  can place this file. And `Elements.xml` of module mention where you to get this file deployed. You will not required to update the master page, but at least needs to add a line which registers this script.

Comment: ok. I think i have found what i needed at "http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/19/add-links-to-promoted-actions-sharefollowsync-in-sharepoint-2013/". I will try to implement this and answer the question with the answer and result. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

May be help for you:

> The Green(Blue) one is called "Suite Bar", while the grey one (with
>   Share, Follow buttons) are called "Promoted Actions"..
>
> Using delegate you can have your custom Suite Bar or Promoted
>   Actions.. Following tutorials should help:
>
> [Add,Remove Links in Top Suitebar (SkyDrive,Sites,NewsFeed) in
>   SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/)
>
> [Add Links to Promoted Actions (Share,Follow,SYNC) in SharePoint
>   2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/19/add-links-to-promoted-actions-sharefollowsync-in-sharepoint-2013/)
>
> ### [Arsalan Adam Khatri](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/93116/48677)

Comment: The links no longer work as of 04/15/2019